# intel 8080: Am I missing something in this code?

Tags: unix, assembly, cpu-registers, intel-8080

Here is a code for the fibonnaci sequence taken from rosettacode.com

```
FIBNCI: MOV  C,  A  ; C will store the counter
    DCR  C      ; decrement, because we know f(1) already
    MVI  A,  1
    MVI  B,  0
LOOP:   MOV  D,  A
    ADD  B      ; A := A + B
    MOV  B,  D
    DCR  C
    JNZ  LOOP   ; jump if not zero
    RET         ; return from subroutine
```

If the value taken from A is originally 0 and we decrement C, does C become -1?  if so what happens to that value at the 2nd DCR; and what does the the JNZ instruction see or do?

This is my first contact with assembly language so its a bit confusing at the moment.  I'm thinking that if C is already -1 and counting when we reach the JNZ instruction, wouldn't this code be stuck in a loop?  Or is the JNZ looking elsewhere?

Comment: Your posted code does not show what is in `A` originally. From the looping of `C` it looks as though `A` should have been the number of Fibonacci terms you wanted to calculate.

Answer (score 4):

Intel 8080 registers `A, B, C, ...` are 8 bit.

So if `A` was `0`, then `C` becomes `-1`, which is encoded in 8 bits as `0b11111111` (all eight bits set to 1). When you treat that as unsigned 8 bit value, it's equal to `255`.

Now if you would increment that value by 1, it would become 256, which in binary is `0b100000000` -> as `C` is 8 bit wide, that value would be truncated to `0b00000000`, which is `0`. So -1 + 1 = 0, as expected (and 255 + 1 = 0 in unsigned Math, because you hit the 8 bit limit, so the value "overflows").

The second `DCR` will decrease that -1/255 value, the C will then contain -2 (which equals to 254 unsigned, as 255 - 1 = 254, and in binary looks like `0b11111110`).

`JNZ` will loop till zero, so that means the loop will run 255 times (for A=0 argument, for A=1 it will run 256 times), until the `C` does reach again zero from the 255 (meanwhile the `A` and `B` registers containing F(n-2) and F(n-1) will overflow many times, thus rendering the result unusable ... the last correct result is for A=13 being 233 I think (too lazy to verify))

Answer (score 2):

For the start check for input < 2:

```
FIBNCI: CPI     2           ;return if A < 2
        RC                  ;F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1
```

The rest of the code seems to be OK. F(2) = 1, F(3) = 2, F(4) = 3, ...

You could modify the code to use double add (DAD) to get a 16 bit result. The largest input for 8 bit result is decimal 13: fib(13) = 233. The largest input for 16 bit result is 24: F(24) = 46368.